# Resources for Programming a 'Watchdog' for a complex system

Tags: .net, asp.net, health-monitoring

I have to write a service to monitor a complex system.  I searched Google for some articles, but didn't find exactly what I was looking for. Does anyone have any good resources for writing a service to monitor a complex system?

Comment: What do you actually need? Describe that complex system.

Comment: A system that would monitor the "health" of different parts of the system running on different machines.  This would include a data acquisition node as well as a database node as well as a web server node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about [health monitoring](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031407-1.aspx).  Here's the online documentation from MSDN on the built-in [health monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx) capabilities in .Net.  Among other things, this lets you define rules for auditing specific events such as errors in the application or failed log-in attempts.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method consists of sending WM_COPYDATA messages from an application that watches the application you want to monitor.  Send the message (with a timeout) and see how long it takes to get a response.  When that respose goes out-of-band, then terminate the process.

I have used [this block of code](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid47D396D37237BF6C0E17E571F516BA72EDB8E02B.aspx) as a base for doing this for a long time.  I don't know where it got started, but kudos to whoever first wrote it.